# Batch, For file search

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, search

I have this code:

```
 H:  
 for /r %%x in (*textfile.txt) do ( 
    findstr "V%String%.$" "%%x"
    if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
       set Location=%%x
       GOTO NEXT
       )
    )
```

It is so slow. I want to do this: `for /r %%x in (H:\**\folderA\folderB\**\textfile.txt) do (...)` but it doesn't find real result.

Comment: You never use `%%x` in your `DO` statement...

Comment: Can you please provide the code prior to the `For` loop and explain what you're wanting to `FindStr`. Also add, whether `LABEL` is the full filename, _( i.e. it has no extension)_, and if it is of type ASCII text. Can you also please explain what `**` is supposed to represent and what you are hoping to do with the result(s). All of that information should be appended to your original question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48770367/edit), _not by adding it to the comment area_.

Comment: I see that you've edited your question, but still not provided the code prior to the `For` loop. Could you therefore please tell us what the content of `%String%` is likely to be, _(`FindStr` can be very picky)_. Could you also confirm that you're looking for a line within a file named `textfile.txt` which is located within `H:\ ` inside any directory tree containing the path `\folderA\folderB\ `. Can you additionally confirm that you're looking for a line which ends with`<upper case V><case sensitive %String% content><any single character>` within that file.

Comment: I am looking for a line which ends this string. I have more than 100 textfile in different folders within different keys, and i want to get location which is equivalent with mine. I know from mine key, it is in H:\**\folderA\folderB\**\textfile.txt .

Comment: This is starting to become tedious! I'll ask again, What does `**` mean? and please provide the content of `%String%`

Comment: Sorry, `**` is `H:\folderwithnumbers\folderA\folderB\folderwithothernumbers\textfile.txt` like `H:\12\2344\folderA\folderB\12345\1512\textfile.txt` or `H:\784\231\folderA\folderB\65432\1234\textfile.txt`
And `%String%` is a key it is a parameter. Example `V1234512 `

Comment: **Don't** use `PATH` as a variable name. It's a system variable to tell `cmd` where to look for it's executables.

Comment: Do you know what those numbers are? Are they always the same?, Given  `%String%`==`V1234512`are you looking to find a line ending with `<upper case VV>1234512<any single character>`. If you cannot explain your situation and what you want, how do you expect us to help you? _We are not sat at your PC!_

Comment: These number is always same. Example `H:\12\23\folderA\folderC\89\22\textfile.txt`, and `H:\12\23\folderA\folderB\43\28\textfile.txt` exist. I need only last one becouse mine key(`V123445`) is in `H:\12\23\folderA\folderB\43\28\textfile.txt`, and i don't want to iterate all file, only where `\folderA\folderB\` is in the path.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Your directory is incorrect. You need to add the user before the file (At least on my computer)

For example, for me to get to folder A and folder B on my desktop I would do `C:\Users\Elliot\Desktop\folderA\folderB\**\LABEL`